# Android Fragment with Appcompactivity

Tags: android, fragment

```
package com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh.HomeActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh.R;

public  class events extends Fragment {

ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);
    return rootView;

};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.events);

    initializeListView();
}




private void initializeListView() {

    listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final String[] items = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView2, items);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String item = items[position];

            Toast.makeText(events.this.getActivity(), item+" is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
} 
}
```

Error: can we put fragment with appcomactivity
Error:(29, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: remove setContentView method from onCreate()

Comment: when going to events activity then app is not running ! if i remove setcontentview

Comment: Remove on create method and call your initializeListView();  method in OnResume method

Comment: initialize your view with private void initializeListView(View view){listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
}

Comment: if i will remove onCreate() method , then how my activity will be displayed without setContentView() for the given layout.

Comment: Fragment **is not** Activity so you don't have a `setContentView()`. Also Fragment is dependent to an Activity container so please show us your Activity code and how you are adding Fragment in your own Activity.

Comment: @Enzokie can u come to my pc via teamviewer and check it out once

Comment: OnCreate is not a part of Fragment, so you cannot use it. call initializeListView from onCreateView itself.

Answer (score 0):

Move and change this

listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

to onCreateView()

```
listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Remove onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

use this code chnage the getview to getActivity(),you can directly call the method under onCreateView

```
public class event extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);
            initializeListView();
            return rootView;

        }

        private void initializeListView() {

            listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);

            final String[] items = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"};


          ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String item = items[position];

                    Toast.makeText(events.this.getActivity(), item+" is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: app is force close stopped

Comment: eError:(36, 48) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(events,int,String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; events cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; events cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; events cannot be converted to Context)